# Use "ar" command to delete a module from an archive

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I try to replace "control.tar.gz" into my archives (.deb files), it works well but sadly some of my archives are compiled using Lzma compression (.xz). So I tried to delete module named "control.tar.xz" into my archive:

`ar d my-archive.deb control.tar.xz`

Without success. I have this error:

`ar: control.tar.xz: not found in archive`

Full log:

```
$ ar tv MyDebian.deb
rw-r--r--       0/0             4 May  3 01:29 2018 debian-binary/
rw-r--r--       0/0          2416 May  3 01:29 2018 control.tar.xz/
rw-r--r--       0/0        125940 May  3 01:29 2018 data.tar.xz/
$ ar d MyDebian.deb control.tar.xz
ar: control.tar.xz: not found in archive
```

Someone know what's wrong with my command?

Thanks

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar This isn't programming or development?

Comment: This question is obviously about the use of `ar` to create a Debian package, which seems quite developer-like. And yes, Debian packages can contain compressed tar files on the inside, although the outer structure is an `ar` archive. `ar` isn't *exclusively* used to make `lib*.a`

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with the `ar d` command. The only conclusion available to us is that your deb file does not contain `control.tar.xz`. What is your evidence to the contrary? `ar tv`?

Comment: I have updated my post, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley The problem statement is debian-specific, but the problem itself is not. I see no reason to close this post, as `ar` is used mainly as a development tool since same decades ago.

Comment: Alain, if your question would be closed here, re-ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

Either you are missing the "/" at the end in the command "ar d MyDebian.deb control.tar.xz" since "ar tv" shows the contents with a "/" at the end.

More pertinent is the fact that you have a "/" at the end of the files contained in the .deb file. IMO, the "/" should not be present. So, you might want to review the generation of the .deb file and why there is a slash present.

If the slash does not matter, try "ar d MyDebian.deb control.tar.xz/" and it should work. Just my 2c.